# Auth Component in Angular 9 giving error in console as follows. Could this be a version issue . How can this be fixed?

Tags: reactjs, angular, user-interface, aws-amplify, angular9

### auth.component.html:

```
<amplify-authenticator></amplify-authenticator>
```

---

### auth.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth',
  templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth.component.scss']
})
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iU1f.png)

### --------------------------------## Heading ##
Error:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewContainerRef' of undefined
at AuthenticatorComponent.push../node_modules/aws-amplify-angular/**ivy_ngcc**/dist/src/components/authenticator/authenticator/authenticator.factory.js.AuthenticatorComponent.loadComponent (authenticator.factory.js:47)
at AuthenticatorComponent.push../node_modules/aws-amplify-angular/**ivy_ngcc**/dist/src/components/authenticator/authenticator/authenticator.factory.js.AuthenticatorComponent.ngOnInit (authenticator.factory.js:31)
at callHook (core.js:4726)
at callHooks (core.js:4690)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4630)
at refreshView (core.js:12013)
at refreshComponent (core.js:13445)
at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11716)
at refreshView (core.js:12051)
at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:13391)

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported in Angular 9.

Found this in the docs

> Angular 9 is not supported in the legacy version of the Angular UI Components. If you app in using Angular 9, please see our new Angular UI Component package.

source: https://docs.amplify.aws/ui-legacy/q/framework/angular

Answer (score 0):

I looked around and found that the package 'aws-amplify-angular' doesn't really work with Angular 9 and above. I have even tried with 11 and it does the same.

The solution is to migrate from 'aws-amplify-angular' to '@aws-amplify/ui-angular'

Steps for integration are available here - https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/angular